# Flood Fill Algorithm with transparent bitmap

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap, flood-fill

I'm working on color filling app which fill colors in parts of bitmap using flood fill algorithm.

When I use bitmap with background it works fine, but when I'v used bitmap with transparent back, it fill color on whole background. I don't know how to fix it. 
[image: Image with transparent back]

Here is block which return drawable converted bitmap -

```
    private Bitmap getBitmap(){
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.drawable.image2,options);
        return imageBitmap;
    }
```

below is my onTouch event code where I passed runs flood fill -

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            pixelColor = canvasBitmap.getPixel((int)touchX,(int)touchY);
            System.out.println("touch color" + pixelColor);
            Point p = new Point((int)touchX,(int)touchY);
            if(!targetColorSet.contains(pixelColor)) {
                floodFillTask = new FloodFillTask(canvasBitmap, p,
                  paintColor, targetColor);
                floodFillTask.execute();
            }
        break;
```

I'm using Queue Linear Flood fill for filling.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: I'v edited my question.

Comment: @akki101, how did you use the QueueLinearFloodFill, please share your implementation that how to use this method and fill the area of image on Touch event. please

Comment: Please see and solve my this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988689/how-to-use-queuelinearfloodfiller-in-my-project